# Loop through each sheets to look for name containing value, do something, loop again looking for new value

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am trying to loop through sheets in a workbook, select those with names alike, save them to a PDF, then loop again but change the name it looks for in the sheets.  The sheets will have in common a number that is 4 digits like `0001` or `0243` and the four digits are important so sheets `0030` and `0003` do not get combined.

I have gotten the code to work on just one name to find (below) but cannot figure out how to make it loop through more names.  Tried making the name an integer and add 1 to it after each loop, tried very briefly to make it loop through array values but that did not work how I tried.

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If sh.Name Like "*0001*" Then

        Worksheets(sh.Name).Select (False)
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            ''' pdf format and save location'''

    End If

Next sh
```

If it could loop through each digit from `0001` to `0300` that would be ideal so I do not need to edit code each time I run it to add the new sheet names.  However if an array will work best I can make a long array for the numbers I know will be present in the file and add new ones each month as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function to grab numbers from the tab name.  Looks like you only want tabs that include 100 thru 300.  How 'bout trying this:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    vNumName = NumOnly(sh.Name)
    If vNumName >= 100 And vNumName <= 300 Then
        Worksheets(sh.Name).Select (False)
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            ''' pdf format and save location'''
    End If
Next sh
```

The function:

```
Function NumOnly(vName As String) As Integer
    vOut = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(vName)
        If Mid(vName, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(vName, i, 1) <= "9" Then vOut = vOut & Mid(vName, i, 1)
    Next
    If Len(vOut) >= 4 Then
        NumOnly = vOut
    Else
        NumOnly = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a code similar to the below:

```
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, K As Long
K = Sheets.Count

For i = 1 to i = K
    t = Sheets(i).Name

    Sheets(i).activate

    ' Do your activities within this loop
Next i
```